# how can I create banner ads space under this bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation, google-mobile-ads

This is my flutter music player app bottomNavigatiob bar code sample.
I want to put ads under this bottom navigation bar. Can you please tell me how can I  create ads space under this bottom navigation bar?
Please help me to do this.

```
bottomNavigationBar: rotated
            ? null
            : SafeArea(
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: _selectedIndex,
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, int indexValue, Widget child) {
                    return AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      height: 60,
                      child: SalomonBottomBar(
                        currentIndex: indexValue,
                        onTap: (index) {
                          _onItemTapped(index);
                        },
                        items: [
                          SalomonBottomBarItem(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
                            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.home),
                            selectedColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          ),
                          SalomonBottomBarItem(
                            icon: const Icon(MdiIcons.music),
                            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.myMusic),
                            selectedColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          ),
                          SalomonBottomBarItem(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.equalizer),
                            title: Text(
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.equalizer,
                            ),
                            selectedColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          ),
                          SalomonBottomBarItem(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.my_library_music_rounded),
                            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.library),
                            selectedColor:
                                Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      
                    );
                   
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

A scaffold has a key by name bottomAppBar. You can add adWidget to bottomAppBar. It should be displayed below the bottom navigation bar.

```dart
Scaffold(
  bottomAppBar : adWidget,
)
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads please use this package. You will get an adwidget. Add that adwidget to bottomappbar